# Насколько термины родства (сват, сватья) распространены в повседневной речи?

Tags: стилистика

Сват и сватья - так называют родителей одного из супругов по отношению к родителям другого супруга.

Вопрос. Насколько эти слова распространены в повседневной разговорной речи? Т.е.например, я иду в гости к родителям девушки, как сказать: я иду в гости к сватам или русские обходятся другими словами?

Дело в том, что у нас в Армении из-за распространенного билингвизма, даже  грамотные люди обходятся армянским словом - хнами. Отсюда и возник вопрос.

Comment: Про распространенность не скажу, но родители девушки в любом случае не сваты. Девушка должна быть женой, чтобы ее родители были сватами для ваших родителей.

Comment: Да, это я и имел в виду.

Comment: С формальной, юридической точки зрения, девушка должна быть для этого женой. Но если парень точно решил жениться на определённой девушке, и её и его родители об этом осведомлены, и уже речь идёт о том, когда именно состоится свадьба, родители с обеих сторон вполне могут называть друг друга сватами... Со мной в школе учился парень из рабочей семьи, у которого в 17-ать лет уже была "законная" невеста. Он много раз говорил: " В воскресенье был у тёщи, поеду на дачу к тёще" и т.п.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В России это зависит от того, к какому социальному слою принадлежит человек. Городская интеллигенция эти слова не употребляет, говоря, например, "мишины, светины" родители. А в деревнях или небольших городках простые люди так говорят. Я живу в Москве, и этих слов от своих знакомых никогда не слышал.

Comment: Но простые люди в Москве эти слова употребляют, конечно.

Comment: В том и дело, я тоже не слышал от русских. Хотя я живу в Армении.